# Add item from Fetch API to Array and Displaying new array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, react-hooks

I'm learning react for the first time, I have an app where it fetches some data from a public API. I currently have it show 10 cards with random items from the API, and I have added a button to fetch a random item from the API and add it to the array, I managed to get the new item added to the array using push() but it does not show in the app itself. How can I make it that the new item is shown in the app as well?

Here is my code

**Home.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Card from './Card';
const Home = () => {

    const [animals, setAnimals] = useState([]);

    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        const newAnimals = animals.filter(animal => animal.id !== id);
        setAnimals(newAnimals);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://zoo-animal-api.herokuapp.com/animals/rand/10')
        .then(res => {return res.json()})
        .then(data => {
            setAnimals(data);
        });
    }, []);

    const handleAddAnimal = () => {
        fetch('https://zoo-animal-api.herokuapp.com/animals/rand/')
        .then(res => {return res.json()})
        .then(data => {
            animals.push(data);
            console.log(animals);
            //what to do after this
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className="home">
            <h2>Animals</h2>
            <button onClick={handleAddAnimal}>Add Animal</button>
            <Card animals={animals} handleDelete={handleDelete}/>
        </div>
      );
}

 
export default Home;
```

**Card.js**

```
const Card = ({animals, handleDelete}) => {
    // const animals = props.animals;

    return (  
        <div className="col-3">
        {animals.map((animal) => (
            <div className="card" key={animal.id}>
            <img
                src={animal.image_link}
                alt={animal.latin_name}
                className="card-img-top"
            />
            <div className="card-body">
                <h3 className="card-title">{animal.name}</h3>
                <p>Habitat: {animal.habitat}</p>
                <button onClick={() => handleDelete(animal.id)}>Delete Animal</button>
            </div>
        </div>
            ))}
    </div>
    );
}
 
export default Card;
```

**App.js**

```
import Navbar from './navbar';
import Home from './Home';

function App() {

  return (
    <section id="app">
      <div className="container">
      <Navbar />
      <div className="row">
        <Home />
      </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Screenshot of what I see now**
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpYuI.png)
(I was also wondering how to fix the items going down instead of side by side but wanted to fix the add button first)

Let me know if there's anything else I should add, any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of what you see right now?

Comment: Sure, I've edited my post and added a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather using array.push() method. You try using

setTheArray([...theArray, newElement]); e.g in your case it will be setAnimals([...animals,data]) in your onClick event.

Let me know doest it solve your issue or not.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, the new item was shown in the app.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const handleAddAnimal = () => {
        fetch('https://zoo-animal-api.herokuapp.com/animals/rand/')
        .then(res => {return res.json()})
        .then(data => {
            setAnimals([...animals,data])
            console.log(animals);
            //what to do after this
        })
    }
```